# Passing values from JavaScript to ASP.NET code-behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, code-behind

**I have an ASP.NET Image control declared as:**

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="SortOrder"
AlternateText="Ascending"
ImageUrl="~/images/sort_ascending.gif"
CssClass="Ascending"
EnableViewState="true"
 />
```

**My JavaScript code is:**

```
function ReverseSort() {
    var img = window.event.srcElement;
    if(img.className == "Ascending") {
        img.className = "Descending";
        img.alt = "Descending";
        img.src = "<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/images/sort_descending.gif") %>";
    } else {
        img.className = "Ascending";  
        img.alt = "Ascending";
        img.src = "<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/images/sort_ascending.gif") %>";
    }
}
```

**I have added an "onclick" attribute to the Image control in my Page_Load code-behind like so:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (IsPostBack)
        return;

    SortOrder.Attributes.Add("onclick", "ReverseSort()");
}
```

**This is my SortOrder.OnClick  event for my Image Control:**

```
if (SortOrder.AlternateText == "Ascending") {
    /* Sort ascending */
} else {
    /* Sort descending */
}
```

My problem is, the SortOrder.AlternateText is always "Ascending".  My code-behind doesn't seem to recognized the changes to the properties made by my javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't expect that to work. The attributes on the server side control do not map to the DOM attributes on the client side. Although setting the `AlternateText` on the server will output the requisite `alt` text, it's not a two way street.

What you could do is use a hidden server side control to keep the state of the sort. A hidden `<asp:checkbox>` which you toggle via javascript will do it.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that's posted back to the server is name-value pairs.  Any attributes changed using javascript with the element remain on the browser.

Comment: Looks like nickd beat me to it by just a few seconds.

Comment: nickd also included the solution. Thanks anyway :)